# Passing conditional arguments to kivy from python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

The idea is pretty simple: I have a slider which affects the speed of a gif.  However, I can't figure out how to trigger the image to get the updated "anim_delay" value from python (or for python to push it to kivy?).

The main file:

```
class BottomRightPart(BoxLayout):

    imgdelay=-1

    def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(self,slider,value):
        if value == 0:
            imgdelay = -1
        elif value == 1:
            imgdelay= 1
        elif value == 2:
            imgdelay = 0.6
        elif value == 3:
            imgdelay = 0.3
        elif value == 4:
            imgdelay = 0
```

The .kv code

```
<BottomRightPart>
    BoxLayout:  
        Image:
            id:FanImg
            source: 'fan.gif'
            anim_delay: root.imgdelay

        Label:
            text: str(int(FanSpeed.value))

        Slider:
            id:FanSpeed
            min:0
            max:4
            step:1
            on_value: root.OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(*args)
```

Where's the missing link?  Any pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing self.
Also set imgdelay to a NumericProperty.

Try this:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class BottomRightPart(BoxLayout):

    imgdelay = NumericProperty(-1)

    def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(self,slider,value):
        if value == 0:
            self.imgdelay = -1
        elif value == 1:
            self.imgdelay= 1
        elif value == 2:
            self.imgdelay = 0.6
        elif value == 3:
            self.imgdelay = 0.3
        elif value == 4:
            self.imgdelay = 0
```

Personally I would create my method something like this:

```
def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(self,slider,value):
    values = [-1, 1, 0.6, 0.3, 0]
    self.imgdelay = values[int(value)]
```

Comment: Good idea for the list.  The slider values would then refer to the positionsin the list?  I'll try that!  Thanks!

Comment: @GroanMan yes and if the values were different you could use a dictionary.

Comment: Works like a charm @EL3PHANTEN!  Thanks for the cue on NumericProperty, I never would have found that by myself!